# Как скрыть виджет в TKINTER python

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно сделать чтобы надпись Main menu появлялась после нажатия кнопки

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.resizable(height= False, width= False)
root.geometry("800x500")
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.9)
root ['bg'] = 'black'
root.title('Test')

def spryatat():
    main_label.grid()



def com():
    destroy_object = [btn,click_label]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()



btn = Button(text = 'click to start', relief= 'solid',
             bg = 'black',
             fg = 'white',
             font = 'Consolas''5',
             command=com)



click_label = Label(root, text = 'Hello,thx for d0wl0and',fg='white', bg= 'black' ,font = 'Consolas')

main_label = Label(root, text= 'Main menu', fg = 'white', bg = 'black', font = 'Consolas')


click_label.pack()
btn.place(x=350, y=150)
main_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: . grid_forget()

Answer (score 0):

Нужна будет переменная с виджетом. Я возьму `elem` для примера

```py
elem.hide()
```

Показать обратно:

```py
elem.show()
```

Повторяюсь, только нужно сохранить сам элемент в переменной